# How to manage handler methods from partials in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, model, razor-pages, partials

I have a `_ContactFrom.cshtml` partial:

```
<form method="post" role="form" id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
...
</form>
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@* More cshtml code... *@
<partial name="_ContactForm"/>
```

`Projects.cshtml`:

```
@* More cshtml code... *@
<partial name="_ContactForm"/>
```

When I try to add an `OnPost` method to handle the form being submitted I get an error depending on where I'm submitting the form:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It seems that there's a conflict in the way the models are used. How and where exactly should I create a handler method for a partial? I also attempted creating a separate `_ContactForm.cshtml.cs` model for the contact form but that didn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you haven't specified a value for the `action` attribute in the form, so it will be posted back to whichever page it appears in. You should have one page/endpoint in your site that is responsible for processing the submitted form and locate your `OnPost` handler there. The most obvious page for that, given your example, is *Contact.cshtml*.

```
<form method="post" role="form" id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="/contact">
...
</form>
```